# change the style of Vuetify table header

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I am trying to change the default color of vuetify table header. I managed to change the header using custom class using code below:

```js
headers = [
    {
        text: "Metering Point",
        align: "start",
        sortable: true,
        value: "meteringpoint",
        class: "success--text title"
    },
]
```

Unfortunately, the checkbox style for select all is still on default color. As the header for the check box is not declared on the array headers so it is not declared with the custom class.

Previously I tried to overwrite it on the  tag with this code below:

```css
.v-data-table-header {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

how do I declare the class for the checkbox? Or is there any possible way for me to overwrite the default styling?

Comment: To overwrite the default styling check what the classes look like after rendering. Then scope them from your component according to their structure.

Comment: Thank you. It works. My solution was `::v-deep .v-data-table-header { background-color: red;}` and it did change the color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by @StevenSiebert. I need to check what is the class after being rendered.

I checked the table header class name and use this code inside the style tag to change the style for that class:

```css
::v-deep .v-data-table-header {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

Here is the reference I found for Scoped CSS in Vue: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 1):

when taking a look at the official Vuetify Docs here: [Vuetify API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#links)

It gives the option to set `checkbox-color` on the **v-data-table** (for all checkboxes) or **v-data-table-header** (for the select all checkbox) which would be my choice considering it is officially supported.

```
<v-data-table
  :items="desserts"
  headers = [
    {
      text: "Metering Point",
      lign: "start",
      sortable: true,
      value: "meteringpoint",
      class: "success--text title"
    },
  ]
  checkbox-color="#DCDCDC"
></v-data-table>
```